# Creality Ender 5 S1 Z Axis wanders while printing

Tags: bed-leveling, z-axis, creality-ender-5

While printing you can see the Z Axis screw slightly moving as the printhead travels across the work space. This results in a tapered print - I see about 0.7 mm taper right to left over 100 mm. This has been constant for a while now, it started after only a few good prints from new. I purchased the printer new in January 2023, and have only sporadically used it, mostly since I cannot print level parts.
I have leveled and releveled manually. I do not believe it is a leveling issue, but something more.

Comment: What's the warranty period on the printer? If you're still within warranty, sounds like it might be easier to just return it & try a new one.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the linear guides are perpendicular to the top frame?